# Problems understanding the AngularJS promise API - AuthenticationService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-promise

Good evening everybody. I startet creating a mobile application with AngularJS,Ionic & Cordova some weeks ago. I try to create a AuthenticationService for this app using a given API.
I checked some tutorials and created this and it seems to work besides the promise handling. I have got a deficit there.
Maybe someone good help me :)

**Here i handle the access to certain pages/states.**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, nextParams, fromState) {

    if ('data' in next && 'authorizedRoles' in next.data) {
        var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
        if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {
                reload: true
            });
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
        }
    }
    if (next.name == 'app.admin' || next.name == 'app.bonus') {

        AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(function (response) {


        }, function (response) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error1!',
                template: 'Sorry, You have to login again.'
            });
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('app.login');

            $log.log(response + '1er');
        });

    }
```

});

**Here I perform the user-login**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, AuthService, $state, $log, $q) {
$scope.data = {};


$scope.login = function (data) {

    $q.all([
    AuthService.login(data.username, data.password),
    AuthService.isAuthenticated()
]).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data[0]); 
        console.log(data[1]); 

        if (data[0] == false) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error!',
                template: 'Sorry, You have to login again.'
            });
        }

        if (data[1] == true) {
            $state.go('app.bonus', {}, {
                reload: true
            });
        } else {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error!',
                template: 'Sorry, You have to login again.'
            });
        }

    });


};
```

})

**Here I created the service handling the user-role, validation & creation of the cookie - Every API-call needs a nonce which is created also**

```
.service('AuthService', function ($q, $http, USER_ROLES, $log) {
var link = 'http://example/api/';
var username = '';
var isAuthenticated = false;
var role = '';
var mycookie = '';
var mynonce = '';

function checkCookie() {


    mycookie = window.localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_COOKIE');
    $log.info(mycookie);
    if (mycookie) {

        $http.get(link + 'get_nonce/?controller=user&method=generate_auth_cookie&insecure=cool').then(
            function (result) {
                if (result.data.status == "ok") {
                    mynonce = result.data.nonce;
                    $log.info(mynonce);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                return false;
            });

        $http.get(link + 'user/validate_auth_cookie/?cookie=' + mycookie + '&nonce=' + mynonce + '&insecure=cool').then(
            function (result) {
                if (result.data.status == "ok") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('LOCAL_COOKIE');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                return false;
            });

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


function doLogin(name, pw) {

    var loginAttempt = false;

    $http.get(link + 'get_nonce/?controller=user&method=generate_auth_cookie&insecure=cool').then(
        function (result) {
            if (result.data.status == "ok") {
                mynonce = result.data.nonce;
                $log.info(mynonce);
            } else {
                loginAttempt = false;
            }
        },
        function (err) {
            loginAttempt = false;
            $log.info(err);
        });


    mycookie = $http.get(link + 'user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pw) + '&nonce=' + mynonce + '&insecure=cool').then(
        function (result) {
            if (result.data.status == "ok") {
                mycookie = result.data.cookie;
                loginAttempt = true;
                username = name;
                if (username == 'MarkusK') {
                    role = USER_ROLES.admin
                } else {
                    role = USER_ROLES.public
                }
                window.localStorage.setItem('LOCAL_COOKIE', mycookie);
                $log.info(mycookie);
            } else {
                loginAttempt = false;
            }
        },
        function (err) {
            loginAttempt = false;
            $log.info(err);
        });

    $log.info('test1' + loginAttempt);

    return loginAttempt;

};

var login = function (name, pw) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (doLogin(name, pw)) {
            resolve('Login success.');
        } else {
            reject('Login Failed.');
        }
    });
};

var validCookie = function () {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (checkCookie()) {
            resolve('Cookie success.');
        } else {
            reject('Cookie Failed.');
        }
    });
};


var logout = function () {
    mycookie = undefined;
    username = '';
    isAuthenticated = false;
    window.localStorage.removeItem('LOCAL_COOKIE');
};

var isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
    if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
        authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
    }
    return (checkCookie() && authorizedRoles.indexOf(role) !== -1);
};



return {
    login: login,
    logout: logout,
    isAuthorized: isAuthorized,
    isAuthenticated: validCookie,
    username: function () {
        return username;
    },
    role: function () {
        return role;
    }
};
```

})

Maybe someone got time to help me and I finally understand the promise API.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nice illustrated definition here:

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html.

Let' say we have the following code (isn't meaning anything it's only to explain the promise concept):

```
var a = 1; 
a = foo();
a = a + 2;
```

Because JavaScript is asynchronous, the second instruction (the call to **foo()**),  won't block the thread.

if **foo()** is **waiting for other ressource** (value from a server), it won't wait and will get into the third instruction (a = 2).

The promise is used to tell JavaScript thread: "Hey don't forget to comeback when I'll be ready, you promised me :)".

Comment: Your statement that "JavaScript is asynchronous" is wrong. It is the type of method that is invoked which is synchronous or not. By default JavaScript is synchronous.